# How important is it to stick to the appropriate HTTP request types when designing an API?

Tags: rest, api, http

Typically when designing an API I attempt to stick to the following structure:

```
GET: /resources (get multiple resources)
POST: /resource (create a single resource)
GET: /resource/:id (get a single resource)
PUT: /resource/:id (update a single resource)
DELETE: /resource/:id (delete a single resource)
```

But sometimes when you are "getting" data the parameters being passed in start to grow beyond what you can include in a query string.  For example in the `GET: /resources` example I provided there might be a number of filters you want to apply to the resources you are selecting.

In this case is it ok to begin using a `POST` so that you can include parameters in the request body? What are the drawbacks from breaking away from adherence to the structure I mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case is it ok to begin using a POST so that you can include parameters in the request body?

Yes, which is to say that there are trade offs.

> What are the drawbacks from breaking away from adherence to the structure I mentioned above?

It interferes with the ability of generic components to intelligently participate in the protocol.

A `GET` request has [safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) semantics; the agent can take advantage of this to do pre-fetching of resources, crawlers can explore the content freely, and so on.

Successful unsafe methods [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) cache entries.  That gets awkward when you want multiple representations of the same resource; fetching one representation via POST will evict other representations of the same resource from the cache.

If all we really wanted was RPC, we could do everything with POST.  See "SOAP", for instance, where all of the messaging in built into the payload, and HTTP is just used as a dumb tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

1)REST is a like design pattern for HTTP communication. It always good to follow REST, especially when you expose your API to public usage or browser to server communication.

2)You can write HTTP Requests even without having a proper REST pattern, But it will lead to unnecessary problems if its browser to server communication. Because most of the modern browsers designed using REST standards, They will understands this pattern very well. By default GET requests will be cached,  instead of GET if you use POST by default it won't cache. So a new request will be fired to server each and every time. So it will lead to a lot of connections, resource, etc.

3)GET - Word itself gives you the meaning it only for getting a resource. likewise, POST and PUT for creating records, DELETE is for deleting, etc.

4)POST-VS-GET - If you use POST you can include RequestBody whereas in GET request you can't.It better to follow GET for getting a resource data